# Add fields to a clientdataset or access it dynamically?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

What's the point in adding fields to TClientDataset if and can do Cds.FieldByName('field').Value?

Is it faster to have the reference?
Is it 'clearer'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with

```
DataSet.FieldByName('field').Value
```

is a performance one.  Each time this is executed, it causes a serial search through the fields collection of the dataset to locate the one with the required name.  This search is not optimised in any way, for instance by using a binary search or hashing algorithm.  So, if there are many fields and/or you are doing this access while iterating the records in the dataset, it can have a significant impact on performance.

That's one reason, but not the only one, to define "persistent" TFields using the Object Inspector.  You can obtain a reference to a particular TField by using the symbolic name known to the compiler and this happens once only, at compile time.  So yes, it is faster than `FieldByName`.  up to you whether you find it clearer.

Other reasons to use persistent TFields include the ease which which calculated fields can be set up and, more importantly, the fact that the calculated field(s) do not need to be accessed via `FieldByName` in the `OnCalcFields` event.  The performance hit of using `FieldByName` versus persistent fields is, of course, multiplied by the number of fields referenced in the `OnCalcField` event and `OnCalcFields` is called at least once for each record in the dataset, even if you do not iterate the dataset records in your own code.

The above is true of all TDataSet descendants, not just TClientDataSets.

Comment: in addition to good answer. there are lot of properties and event handlers that may be configured for persistent fields in design time without polluting sources (though some may prefer latter explicit way)